# alert in WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string LoadLayout()
 {
        try
        {
            List<XmlTag> lstXmlTags = new List<XmlTag>();
            lstXmlTags = parser.GetXmlTags(filePath);

            string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(lstXmlTags );</script>";
            System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "test", script, true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I want to alert `lstXmlTags` for test purpose.Above code run locally but in server its get a problem.I think in server its doesn't able to get `filepath`.So I want to  alert what `lstXmlTags` returns or is it empty.So I  add `RegisterClientScriptBlock` for  showing result.But what I try gives me syntax error.I am not able to use `RegisterClientScriptBlock`.Thanks.

Comment: Very First Thing, get rid of that try/catch block. It serves only to screw up your stack trace.

Comment: Second, why would you expect something from the System.Web.UI namespace to work in a web service?

Comment: @John Saunders So what a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing client side variables with server side. Here's one way you could achieve that:

```
[WebMethod]
public string LoadLayout()
{
    try
    {
        List<XmlTag> lstXmlTags = parser.GetXmlTags(filePath);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = serializer.Serialize(lstXmlTags);

        string script = string.Format("alert(JSON.stringify({0}));", json);
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "test", script, true);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Things to notice here:

- I have used a JSON serializer (The built-in [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class) to make sure that the server side variable `lstXmlTags` is properly encoded before passing it to a cilent side function
- I have gotten rid of the `<script type="text/javascript">` tags because you have passed true as last parameter of the [`RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) function which means (I quote from the documentation): *A Boolean value indicating whether to add script tags.* So if you set this to true the method will already add those tags for you and you should not be manually adding them once again.
- I have used the `JSON.stringify` method inside the alert function. This method is natively built-into all modern browsers and allows to convert a javascript variable definition into a string so that you get a friendly display. But of course you could have directly used the variable if you wanted to: `alert({0}[1].SomeProperty);` will display some property of the second element in your collection.

Remark: For debugging purposes it's far better to use `console.log` and a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug instead of alerting around with some modal windows.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

1. Call a web method via JavaScript
2. Call alert or whatever when web method returns or is done.

For more reference visit this: [Implementing Client Callbacks Programmatically Without Postbacks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx)

Comment: I call web method from javascript. That's not a problem.I want to alert what `lstXmlTags` in web method. There are other codes so I am not posting all codes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will not work as is. The problem is that when you execute `alert(lstXmlTags)`, it will be attempting to find a variable called `lstXmlTags`, which does not exist and would tend to explain the error you are getting.

What I would do is something like this:

```
string lstXmlTagsText = string.Join("\n", lstXmlTags.Select(t => t.ToString()).ToArray());
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(" + lstXmlTagsText + ");</script>";
```

Then register the script as you were before. The key thing is to convert the `List<XmlTag> lstXmlTags` object into some human-readable form. You'll note I've just done this with the `ToString` method of each `XmlTag` - you may need to use a different method if `ToString` isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set a breakpoint and attach to the w3wp process and debug and then you can see the value of your variable?

Comment: project is deploy in window azure for test purpose so this method is not work.

Comment: What about remote debugging?